# Regex to parse artist and title from a file

Tags: regex

I have the following file:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:36,Armand van Helden Featuring La Rok - Let Me Lead You
C:\Users\Public\Music\Sample Music\Armand van Helden Featuring La Rok - Let Me Lead You.mp3
#EXTINF:19,Ann Nesby - Loving is Really My Game
C:\Users\Public\Music\Sample Music\Ann Nesby - Loving is Really My Game.mp3
#EXTINF:19,Thomas Toccafondi feat. Kaysee - I've Changed (Earnshaw & Jones Remix)
C:\Users\Public\Music\Sample Music\Thomas_Toccafondi_feat._Kaysee-I've_Changed_(Earnshaw_&_Jones_Remix)-DUFF028-1(320k).mp3
#EXTINF:57,Terry Hunter feat. Terisa Griffin - Wonderful (Abicah Soul's Wonderful Remix)
C:\Users\Public\Music\Sample Music\Terry_Hunter_feat._Terisa_Griffin-Wonderful_(Abicah_Soul's_Wonderful_Remix)-TB005-1(320k).mp3
```

I am trying to write a regular expression that will parse out artist and title into two separate groups so the first group would contain the artist:

```
Armand van Helden Featuring La Rok
Ann Nesby
Thomas Toccafondi feat. Kaysee
Terry Hunter feat. Terisa Griffin
```

And the second group would contain the title:

```
Let Me Lead You
Loving is Really My Game
I've Changed (Earnshaw & Jones Remix)
Wonderful (Abicah Soul's Wonderful Remix)
```

The parsed information should come from the part right after #EXTINF: followed by any number. I want to ignore the actual file name.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What if - appears in the artist name or the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/^#EXTINF:\d+,(.*?) - (.*)/
```

Artists are in group 1

Titles are in group 2

Answer (score 0):

If all of the tracks have the same format (#, Artist - Track) then I would use find the '-' in every line, take whats before it as the #, Artist and whatever is after it as the Track. It would just be a simple *-*. Then you can do some processing on it to split it up. For the Artist you can use a lookahead/lookbehind or just a [0-9]+, then grab the rest of the line.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

artists:

```
/^#EXTINF:\d+,([^-]+) - /
```

titles:

```
/^#EXTINF:\d+,[^-]+ - (.+)/
```